# KDE: Task switcher does not show thumbnails

Tags: 20.04, kde, window-manager

I have upgraded 2 laptops to Ubuntu 20.04.

On laptop A I can choose the KDE Task Switcher 'Grid' (which works perfectly). I cannot choose that on laptop B. I can install 'Thumbnail Grid' but that does not show thumbnails when switching.

I have the feeling this is because laptop B has an older graphics card and that KDE has disabled some eye candy that just happens to also remove the thumbnail window in task switcher.

Some 3D features *do* work on laptop B: Task switcher 'Flip switch' shows the windows in smooth 3D. I just happen to like 'Grid' much better.

How can I change to 'Grid' and show the thumbnails for all windows, just like I have on laptop A? Can I possibly just copy some file in `~/.kde`?

Answer (score 2):

I had to change the compositor from OpenGL 2.0 to OpenGL 3.1.

If you search for "Compositor" in settings or go to Display and Monitor you should see it.

Comment: This did not work for me.

Comment: I've had to "Enable on startup" in Compositor settings - on an Optimus laptop it looks like it's being switched off when dedicated GPU is turned off (to save power)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the way thumbnails of windows are displayed, while you switch between open windows (tasks) using `Alt + Tab`, via the following setting:

`Window Management > Task Switcher > Visualization > 2nd option which is a drop down`

Change the selected option, from the drop down, then click on `Apply` and check if the problem is solved.

You can download more `Task Switchers`, which add effects/animations etc, using the button located to the bottom right of the window, with title `Get New Task Switchers..`.

Enjoy!